# How to get Multiple selected listbox items to another listbox

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, listbox

In my ASP.NET application I have two listboxes, say Listbox1 and Listbox2. Listbox1 having some listitems and which is in Multiple Selection Mode. If I Press the transfer button the selected items in Listbox1 should be moved to Listbox2. I have tried it for Single Selection Move and it works fine.
Now I need help for multiselection.

Code for Single Selection

```
     strItemText = lstAvailableItems.SelectedItem.Text
     iItemCode = lstAvailableItems.SelectedValue
     lstAvailableItems.Items.Remove(New ListItem(strItemText, iItemCode))
     lstSelectedItems.Items.Add(New ListItem(strItemText, iItemCode))
```

Listbox image

[image: ListBox]

If I press the > button single selected item will be moved from Available Items listbox to selected items list box. How to do this for multiple selection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A combination of my original, and @Arman's.

```
    Dim lstRemoveItem As New List(Of ListItem)

    For Each li As ListItem In lstAvailableItems.Items
        If li.Selected Then
            lstRemoveItem.Add(New ListItem(li.Text, li.Value))    
            ' can't remove from the collection while looping through it       
        End If
    Next

    For Each li As ListItem In lstRemoveItem
        lstSelectedItems.Items.Add(li)       ' add to "selected" items
        lstAvailableItems.Items.Remove(li)   ' remove from the original available items
    Next
```

Comment: Its working fine thanks.. In my lstAvailableItems I am having 4000 items. while debugging its taking too longer to execute it to get selected items.. Is there any other simple way to do this?

Comment: @Manivel, GetSelectedIndices gets the array of index values for currently selected items, but I have no idea how fast it is.  `Dim selectedValues() As Integer = lstAvailableItems.GetSelectedIndices()`  With that many items, using a different user interface element would generally be recommended (perhaps letting user search by partial item like AR12FC and then selecting from a shorter list -- but I'm not a UI expert).

Answer (score 0):

Use List. Iterate all items in the listbox and whatever it finds to be selected, add it to the list.

```
Dim lstRemoveItem As New List(Of ListItem)

For Each _item As ListItem In lstAvailableItems.Items
    If _item.Selected Then
        lstRemoveItem.Add(_item)
        'here, method to add item to the first list.
    End If
Next

For Each _item As ListItem In lstRemoveItem
    lstSelectedItems.Items.Add(_item)
Next
```

Not exactly what you want, but you can configure the variables easily.